# How to declare a global int in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am creating a global int variable in iPhone app but it gives error.

I am declaring in this way:

```
 AppDelegate.h

 int maxglobal;
```

When I assign this to any other values it say object can not set to property in other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C:

```
@property (assign) int maxglobal; // define this in app delegate
```

C:

```
int maxglobal; // define this outside any class and it's "global"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .h file do this

`double GlobalVariable=0.0;`

Take care that you do this above `@synthesize` and you are done:)

Comment: The question is about `int` not double !

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
AppDelegate.h:
@interface AppDelegate{
    int maxglobal;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) int maxglobal;

AppDelegate.m
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize maxglobal;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use extern keyword to declare the variable as global

```
extern int maxglobal;
```